# Convergence or divergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

The sum is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n}$$ Is this convergent or divergent? I tried to use the divergent test but the test fail because $a_n = (n+2^n)/(n+3^n) = 0 $ as $n$ goes to infinity. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: there are other tests. You could do this by comparison, or by ratio, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to resort to the "big mallets" of the Ratio Test or the Limit Comparison Test, you could also note that

$$ \frac{n + 2^n}{n + 3^n} \ < \ \frac{2 \ \cdot \ 2^n}{n + 3^n} \ < \ \frac{2 \ \cdot \ 2^n}{ 3^n} \ , \ \text{for} \ n \ \ge \ 1 \ , $$

the last term in this inequality being the general term of a convergent geometric series.

Comment: This only show a_n converges to 0 as n goes to infinity. The divergence test fails because a_n =0 does not guarantee convergence or divergence of the sum of the series.

Comment: I am using the (simple) Comparison Test:  your general term is smaller than the general term of a known convergent series.  Thus, your series also converges.