# Show whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k+k^2}{4^k +1}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Here's the problem to be solved:

> Show whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k+k^2}{4^k +1}$ converges or diverges

**My attempt**

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k+k^2}{4^k +1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^k+k^2}{4^k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (3/4)^k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{4^k}$

The first term in the last equality converges, however, I'm struggling to show whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{4^k}$ converges or diverges. My hypothesis is that it converges, since $4^k$ is growing much faster than $k^2$, so I somehow must show that it's less than or equal to something else.

I'd be glad if you could share any tips. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy ratio test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Again, several high rep users fail to search for similar threads. A few seconds with Approach0 points at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3771044/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546405/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1796952/11619), and probably dozens of similar threads. Disappointing.

Comment: [Copy/pasting a formula is easy](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B3%5Ek%2Bk%5E2%7D%7B4%5Ek%20%2B1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

For $k \ge 2$, we have $3^k \ge k^2$, and that's all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$4^k = e ^{k\log 4} > \frac{k^4 (\log4)^4}{4!}$$

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it worked :)

Comment: @Tanamas: You're welcome.  Using the expansion $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots$   justifies your hypothesis that the exponential function grows faster than any polynomial function.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Think about $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$ and its derivatives. Notice that $$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}$$ then try multiplying both sides by $x$ and take another derivative and see what infinite sum we find.

This tells you it converges as well as its sum.

Comment: It worked using ur method aswell. That's a nice tool to remember :)

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to use *asymptotic analysis*:

As $k^2=o(3^k)$, we have $3^k+k^2\sim_\infty3^k$. Similarly, $4^k+1\sim_\infty 4^k$. Therefore
$$\frac{3^k+k^2}{4^k +1}\sim_\infty\biggl(\frac 34\biggr)^{\mkern-6mu k},$$which is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Isn't this kind of similar to the Limit Comparison Test? (Not that I am denying the validity of your answer)

Comment: @imranfat: In english speaking countries, it is indeed known as the *lLimit Comparison Test*. I prefer to place it in its real context, which is Asymptotic Analysis  and more specifically, the notion of asymptotically equivalent functions.

Comment: That makes sense. I did the limit comparison test on the given problem and that was a breeze. Didn't want to post my answer because it looked too similar to yours...

Comment: I agree with you: it is generally the simplest & fastest way to determine limits.